# Creating custom QAbstractItemModel from comma seperated text file

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I have this issue that my Qtableview gets extreme slowly after inserting 100.000 rows and specially using multiple select.

So after some reasearch I have decided to use my own model that inherits from QAbstractItemModel. But the issue is I have no clue how to use it since, the text file can change. fx. I can load a file with 5 columns and 50.000 rows, and after sometime it can have 15 columns and 10.000 rows.
the data does not need to be changed, so its only read only.
Anyone can help me with this problem?

My "empty" custom model is here

```
#include "customabstractmodel.h"

CustomAbstractModel::CustomAbstractModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
}

QVariant CustomAbstractModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    // FIXME: Implement me!
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (value != headerData(section, orientation, role)) {
        // FIXME: Implement me!
        emit headerDataChanged(orientation, section, section);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

QModelIndex CustomAbstractModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    // FIXME: Implement me!
}

QModelIndex CustomAbstractModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // FIXME: Implement me!
}

int CustomAbstractModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid())
        return 0;

    // FIXME: Implement me!
}

int CustomAbstractModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid())
        return 0;

    // FIXME: Implement me!
}

QVariant CustomAbstractModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    // FIXME: Implement me!
    return QVariant();
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (data(index, role) != value) {
        // FIXME: Implement me!
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags CustomAbstractModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable; // FIXME: Implement me!
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    // FIXME: Implement me!
    endInsertRows();
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::insertColumns(int column, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginInsertColumns(parent, column, column + count - 1);
    // FIXME: Implement me!
    endInsertColumns();
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    // FIXME: Implement me!
    endRemoveRows();
}

bool CustomAbstractModel::removeColumns(int column, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginRemoveColumns(parent, column, column + count - 1);
    // FIXME: Implement me!
    endRemoveColumns();
}
```

Edit #1 Csv data (Not real information, randomized)

name,phone,email,address,city,zip
Chavez, Lisandra F.,1-498-913-8181,ac.fermentum.vel@semperrutrumFusce.org,Ap #123-1044 Sed Rd.,Drayton Valley,21833
Humphrey, Briar W.,1-583-466-4027,Morbi.accumsan.laoreet@Loremipsumdolor.net,Ap #642-6497 Id Rd.,Lochgilphead,16394
Benson, Tasha H.,1-898-918-7872,consequat@enimEtiam.ca,P.O. Box 197, 4720 Ipsum. St.,Telford,56688
Emerson, Susan P.,1-190-818-1919,dignissim@liberoatauctor.ca,P.O. Box 482, 7813 Dolor. Ave,San Antonio,M8C 7F6
Dunn, Alexander U.,1-222-379-2231,libero.Donec.consectetuer@nonegestasa.ca,803-958 Lectus Rd.,Raleigh,74078

Comment: As you need a table (no hierarchy) you should rather go with `QAbstractTableModel` where such functions as `index()` etc. are already implemented, and  must implement only `rowCount()`, `columnCount()`, and `data()`.

Comment: So in short you want to display a table backed by a CSV data source, but the data can change? That's quite complicated if you want to reflect the changed file in a table view or do you just want to display it once and refresh manually (with a button or something)?

Comment: In which form you get your data? Bring an example, please.

Comment: @vahancho Okay, I can go for that. but again, what is my data,except of QString, I mean what should I implement there? Edit: I read the file, and I split them by comma. at the moment I use QStandartitemmodel where I add QStandaritem to it

Comment: Also in a CSV file you usually have no way to jump directly to a specific row, if you want to stream the data from the file you have to have way to to that if properly done. Reading the file from the beginning and skipping rows is possibly but not so clean I guess, if it's not to large you should read the whole data into memory, but only display what you need with that table view.

Comment: @xander thats what I do right now. I have no issues with reading it. and yea, the program restarts once I know I have new data. the only issue I have here to display them on Qtableview with QAbstractItemModel/QAbstractItemTable

Comment: @neotrix3 In simply terms the `data` method is being called by the view with a row and column index and the role, which can be display role by default to display the data as `QString` in the view in your case. How you get the data with that column and row index is up to your model, the class is not helping you with that!

Comment: @neotrix3, IMO, you prioritize the issues wrongly:) Implementing a custom model is relatively easy, however reading a huge file is more important, because model assumes a random-access to your data. You have two choices: 1) Read the whole data into memory in transform it into a form of vector of strings, 2) Implement quick access to the given line in your text file, so that the model can quickly read it.

Comment: @vahancho thats true. and I have went to the choice, reading whole data and have them in vector as qstring or should I save each line as qstringlist in the vector? and if its possible, would u please add it as answer if u have examples?

Comment: @neotrix3, surely I can. I just asked for a small example of your data. Please update your question and add that information.

Comment: Have you seen this: [Handling CSV](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_CSV)? There is also a custom CSV model implementation that might help you.

Comment: @xander no I did not see it, it looks promising, I will give a look to it now.

Comment: @vahancho test csv added

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we read the whole file into memory, I would implement the model (subclass from `QAbstractTableModel`) in the following way:

```
CustomAbstractModel::CustomAbstractModel(const QString &filePath,
                                         QObject *parent)
    :
        QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    // Parse the file and store its data in an internal data structure
    QFile file(filePath);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            // Assuming that m_data is a std::vector<QString>
            m_data.emplace_back(in.readLine());
        }
    }    
}

QVariant CustomAbstractModel::headerData(int section,
                                         Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                         int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole &&
        !m_data.empty())
    {
        // Read the column names from the first line        
        const QString &firstLine = m_data.front();
        QStringList headers = firstLine.split(',');
        return headers.at(section);
    }    
}

int CustomAbstractModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!m_data.empty())
    {
        return m_data.size() - 1; // First line is the column names data
    }
    return 0;
}

int CustomAbstractModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(!m_data.empty())
    {
        const QString &firstLine = m_data.front();
        return firstLine.count(",") + 1;
    }
    return 0;    
}

QVariant CustomAbstractModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (m_data.empty() && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        // First line is the header data.
        const QString &line = m_data[index.row() + 1];
        QStringList columnData = firstLine.split(',');
        return columnData.at(index.column());
    }
    return QVariant();    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to load the model in the tableView, but its crashing when Im setting the model.  /*     ui->tableView->setModel(model); */

Comment: You must debug it. I cannot do it for you, unfortunately.

Comment: Well I hope I can fix it than, Well thank you for your help!